# $http.post using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'd like to post an object using AngularJS but it doesn't work.

```
console.log(user); // {firstname: 'toto', lastname: 'tutu'}

$http.post('/user/create', user).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response); // undefined
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error); // undefined
});
```

Main issue : I'm not able to recieve the POST request in my NodeJS controller using `app.post` and `request.body`.

NodeJS Controller :

```
app.post('/user/create', function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.body); // undefined
});
```

Comment: `but it doesn't work` <= so what does happen? Do both of your functions execute or only the 2nd one or the 1st one? How do you know both are undefined? Have you tried using PostMan or some other tool to see if you can manually POST to your NodeJS controller? Any other troubleshooting you have done that you can share?

Comment: Is this actually the code you are running? I don't think it is possible for response to be undefined

Comment: As Igor has asked: What does happen? It would also be helpful to see how you have setup your Node server.

Comment: The problem is most likely in your NodeJS proxy code exposing the controller, could you post that?

Comment: Edit#1, you can see my NodeJS controller.

Comment: Add response.send("something"); in your callback, see if anything happens.

Comment: are you getting 404 or 200? maybe a 500 from the serverside?

Comment: When I add `response.send("something")` I'm not redirected... It happens nothing.

Comment: What do you see in network tab (Developer tool F12) for this request? Any error in console?

Comment: I get a 500 internal error.

Comment: can you provide err stack trace from server?

Comment: Add all your `route.js` code and also your `server.js` code. Also, have ypu tried using an http rest-client like `Postman` or doing that via `curl`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the link you are posting to, I wouldnt know how you are testing this, but if you are testing in your own server with localhost, you should post to

```
"http://localhost:(portNumberYouOpenedForExpress)/user/create"
```

for testing